# Javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript

I'm not even sure of how to name what I want. So let me explain it by giving an example.

While firefox uses textContent, other browsers supports the innerText property. By the way, please correct me if I use wrong terminology. Anyways, so far everything is ok. But I want something like the following:

```
document.getElementById(id).iText = "blablabla" 
//or
var x = document.getElementById(id).iText;
//where iText is something like:

if(e.innerText) return innerText;
else return textContent;
```

I do not want to use a function for this stuff. Also, please tell me the name of this "thing", if exists, as I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Ahh yes, the cruel mistress... it has many names depending where you're from. I'm from the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and it's called [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/). In plain JS you can always use a `var x=document.body.innerText?document.getElementById(id).innerText:document.getElementById(id).textContent;`

Comment: Yes I know that, but since I will reference a lot of times and with different ID's I do not want to check it all the times. I want to create a property which is crossbrowser. And apparently, till now, the best answer is Andy's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the things you want are called 'getters' (and for setting the text, 'setters'). For documentation, see eg. [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters)

On DOM nodes, IE does not reliably support adding such properties (not before IE8, at least, see [this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). However, Webkit (Chrome) and Gecko (Firefox) seem to be happy to let you modify the DOM prototypes. Which leaves you with:

```
try {
    if (!('innerText' in HTMLElement.prototype)) {
        HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__("innerText", function() { return this.textContent; });
    }
} catch (ex) {/*uh oh*/}
```

You could use analogous syntax to define a setter:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.__defineSetter__("innerText", function(newVal) { return this.textContent = newVal; });
```

While this may work, I would still highly recommend using a library of your choice (jQuery, Prototype, MooTools, YUI, whatever) for this kind of thing. Of course you can make stuff like this work all by yourself, but for most cases, your efforts are better spent on writing your actual application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even though Andy's answer was the closest one till you answered, I shift the correct answer from him to you as you replied my question perfectly :) This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Shaokan, Gijs: note that `__defineSetter__` and `__defineGetter__` are both non-standard and may not be defined in browsers that support `textContent` only; like the BlackBerry web browser, for instance.  It may also, in the future, be dropped from some browsers in favour of the standard `Object.defineProperty()` method.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to refer to `innerText` or `textContent` a few times, you can do something like this:

```
// Check which is supported:
var textProp = "textContent" in document.body ? "textContent" : "innerText";

// And when you need it:
var text = document.getElementById("myId")[textProp];
```

Comment: @Shaokan: No problem.  Don't forget there are some small differences between `innerText` and `textContent` :-)

Comment: Yeah I know :) but I need the text inside the paragpraph and innerHTML is not dismissing them. Since Firefox is not using innerText, the closest thing to what I want is textContent :) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which "thing" you mean, but you can use a logical OR to retrieve the text:

```
var text = x.textContent || x.innerText;
```

This returns `x.innerText` if `x.textContent` is not defined (and `x.textContent` if it is defined). It is a very common shortcut.

Assigning is a bit more tricky and I'm not even sure if you can assign to these properties. However, if you can, then it would have the same effect as assigning to `innerHTML` (apart maybe from rendering HTML), namely replacing the whole content with the given string.
But `innerHTML` is supported in every browser and hence easier to use.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure either of what that "thing" is. I'm not sure even if it exists lol. That's why I don't know how to ask :)

Comment: It's probably more appropriate to have `innerText` as the fallback, since there are slight differences between that and `textContent` and all major edge browser releases support `textContent` now.

Comment: @AndyE: Yeah, actually I was not sure about the order anymore... updated.

Answer (score 2):

Embed jQuery and then simply use `$('#' + id).text()`.

That's the only proper way. While JavaScript allows you to define properties which have a getter, extending host objects (and DOM nodes are host objects) may lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude but I also don't want to use jQuery :)

Comment: Then you have to stay with ugly code that returns whatever property that has a value.

Answer (score 0):

either do sth like

```
var x = elem.innerText || elem.textContent || "";
```

or simly use jquery and let it handle it for you

```
var x = $('myElement').text();
```